# docker-compose not seeing my index.php but docker run does

Tags: php, docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
ENV APP_DIR /app
ENV APPLICATION_ENV development
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
EXPOSE 5000
VOLUME $APP_DIR
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:5000", "-t", ".", "index.php"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - logvolume01:/var/log
        links:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis
volumes:
    logvolume01: {}
```

This output shows as expected on http://localhost:5000 when I run:

```
docker build -t my-app .
docker rm my-app && docker run -it -p 5000:5000 -v "$PWD":/app --name my-app my-app
```

But when I run this:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get PHP error on http://localhost:5000 saying the following:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I don't see the COPY command in your Dockerfile, are you adding that?

Comment: seems like due to directory structure, can you show your directory structure, or you can add `command: ls /app/` in the php docker-compose to view the directory strcuture.

Comment: @kiran.koduru this is a development server and I'll be adding files on the fly. It's working with `docker run`, should I still have COPY command?

Comment: @Adiii, I don't have any directories. index.php is right beside Dockerfile for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the following from Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 5000
VOLUME $APP_DIR
```